DNN Eventlog filling up with 2sxc errors after upgrade, what could cause this?
After upgrading to 2sxc 17.9 we see the Eventlog filling up with the following error:
AbsoluteURL:/api/2sxc/app/auto/query/System.EntityPicker/Default

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:c46d5883-be47-48dd-b1cc-8d6cde0dac5c

AssemblyVersion:

PortalId:-1

UserId:-1

TabId:-1

RawUrl:

Referrer:

UserAgent:

ExceptionHash:QNQ1dFJLAV3lVWxfsQiVlPXM8bk=

Message:The operation was canceled.

StackTrace:

   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()

Perhaps related, when the customer saves a news article they get an error "Had an error talking to the server (status 0)". The article seems to be saved though.
It looks like this is happening on other dnn installations as well where we upgraded to 2sxc 17.9. When we edit or add a news article and then click the save button it makes 1 or more calls to the entitypicker api which get aborted because the save action closes the request before it can return a response.

no idea. sounds a bit like a request was stopped, but I'm not sure. Can't help with the given information. I suggest you find out more specifically what requests cause this, and then check 2sxc-Insights for those requests, to see what's happening.

It looks like the content app is working ok, but other apps like the news app show this error in the eventlog, When I try to add an article or edit an article it will still save the data, but it generates about 20 errors in the log.
When I look with F12 it seems  it has something to do with the related entitys. So I see errors in calls like:
http://[website]/api/2sxc/app/auto/query/System.EntityPicker/Default?typeNames=Category&appId=10&itemIds=5f209582-c2fa-4253-924f-52644913f37a,34d3610a-59a1-41c2-8cfe-95eb453c2cb2,2fb60dc0-f72a-4422-8f3c-43aa995aca57&$select=Title,Id,Guid

Also, on editing (or adding) an article it calls the entities just fine, using the same method as described above. So I can select categories and authors. It seems to call these methods again after clicking on the save button and then it says something like "A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the channel closed before a response was received"

To add to this, we tried installing News 5 on a subsite of this installation. And when it added the modules it gave a lot of errors. When I refreshed, the news functionality seems to be working. So I will post the errors, maybe this will say something to you:
'''

[A]AppCode.Data.News cannot be cast to [B]AppCode.Data.News. Type A originates from 'App-00050-AppCode-hrlf0uqa, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\2sxc.bin\App-00050-AppCode-hrlf0uqa.dll'. Type B originates from 'App-00050-AppCode-oqta02vl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\2sxc.bin\App-00050-AppCode-oqta02vl.dll'.

at RazorHost.RazorViewarticleinformation.Execute() in C:\home\site\wwwroot\portals\1\2sxc\news5\bs5\article information.cshtml:line 8
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Razor.Internal.DnnRazorCompiler.Render(RazorComponentBase page, TextWriter writer, Object data) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Razor\Dnn\Razor\Internal\DnnRazorCompiler.cs:line 77...

Daniel, btw. this installation had the plugin/extension you made for us for the google auto translations. Perhaps we should activate this somewhere? Just don't know where. If you can tell us, that would be ..... great.

So the errors are all completely unrelated. e. the AppCodeDataNews is a compile problem which goes away after a restart or after changing any file in the AppCode folder.

Google Translate is also not involved.

I suggest you stick to the initial error - my guess is some data (relationship) was force-deleted by someone who ignored warnings. Finding this will probably fix it?

Well, like I said, on a subportal, so www.website.nl/subportal I installed the News 5 app, and this gives the same errors. So I do not think it is a force deleted item.
When I open the add / edit dialog, and select a category the call to the categories api is ok, however when I click on save it seems to make the same call again which is then cut of or something. That's probably why it is an 'The operation was canceled' exception. I just don't know what to do about it....

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Also tried upgrading to 17.10 since is said something about "improve data being sent back and forth between edit-ui and server", but that did not help....

You may be running 2 or more DNN Instances that share the same Application Pool in IIS, try separating the Application Pool
